# Wine [internal error]

Tags: wine

I encountered this error when I wanted to run a program (program is Spitfire Audio App)

[image]

I did a little digging and some say because it's running an old version of windows but when I opened up `winecfg` it says it's running win 10

[image]

should I change something within the `winecfg` or within the `regedit`
Thanks!

Comment: Before anything else I suggest you google "Windows software name + winehq". If it was tested already the first or among the first results will be a link to Wine's database where you can check whether it worked or not, caveats, workarounds, etc.

Comment: Which program are you trying to run? Do you see it at https://appdb.winehq.org/ ?

Comment: Yes, the program is Spitfire Audio App, it also says it works but the test result is already old